# MS Access select fields from multiple rows

Tags: ms-access, select

I have a table like:

`id|---|First|---|Second`

```
1  ---  10   ---  100
2  ---  20   ---  200
3  ---  30   ---  300
4  ---  40   ---  400
5  ---  50   ---  500
```

I want to make a select query that returns:

```
1 -- 10 -- 200
2 -- 20 -- 300
3 -- 30 -- 400
4 -- 40 -- 500
```

Get the (i) data from the id and First column and the (i+1) data from the Second column.
How can I do that?

```
i -- i -- i+1
```

Thank you....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this SQL statement:

`SELECT TableName.ID, TableName.First, TableName_1.Second FROM TableName AS TableName_1 INNER JOIN TableName ON TableName_1.ID = TableName.ID+1;`

where `TableName` is name of your table.

Or with `WHERE` clause:

`SELECT TableName.ID, TableName.First, TableName_1.Second FROM TableName, TableName AS TableName_1 WHERE TableName_1.ID = TableName.ID+1`